# My navbar dropdown will shrink when click in tab/mobile mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Version: 3.3.5

I used the default codes of bootstrap navbar codes from w3schools. Now, I used the codes to a page that I'm creating but whenever I switched to mobile/tab mode by resizing the browser — the dropdown sub-menu will show and the whole menu will shrink after.

The problem is, Page 1 dropdown button on the gif will not display its submenu -instead the whole menu will shrink. It's supposed to display its submenu (Page 1-1, Page 1-2, Page 1-3).

Kindly check the gif I've created.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiX9E.jpg

I tried the same code and it works perfectly. The Page 1 dropdown will display its submenu and the whole menu will not shrink. Check the fiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/4u0ugk1p/

I guess there's a conflict in my codes but I already removed and commented out all the possible reasons for this behavior. Can anyone explain what's happening?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Please post a complete working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS). [mcve]

Comment: Im confused by the question, its dropping down just as its meant to in bootstrap on mobile. What is the problem? Is it not leading to the right page?

Comment: @PX5 can i know which version of bootstrap css you are using???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tzaLaybb/) here,its working now

Most of the time, its because `jQuery` isn't linked to the page correctly. Or `bootstrap.js` is referenced before `jQuery.js`. Make sure you have those linked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for me to test this solution without the full code, but try not setting href="#" on the dropdown anchor.

Instead, try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13818/

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="cursor:pointer;">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#page1-1">Page 1-1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#page1-2">Page 1-2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#page1-3">Page 1-3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="examplePage" id="page1-1">
    PAGE 1-1
</div>
<div class="examplePage" id="page1-2">
    PAGE 1-2
</div>
<div class="examplePage" id="page1-3">
    PAGE 1-3
</div>

<div class="examplePage" id="page2">
    PAGE 2
</div>

<div class="examplePage" id="page3">
    PAGE 3
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.examplePage {
    height:400px;
    width: 100%;
    background: salmon;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: There's no external external css because I once deleted all the css codes to test its behavior. The design is pure bootstrap. I'm wondering what's the reason behind this behavior because the codes are actually working fine when I tried it on fiddle. But when I tried it on my page, it's acting weird and I don't know why.